# Not sure about the use of pointers C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm new to C++. I have problem with the code below.  The last function object.f() in main function should return 120, but it returns 100 and I don't know why.

SOLVED  method g of class B should take reference parameter.

This is the header file

```
class A {
  string p;
  float b = 0;

public:

  A(string &&p, int b=0);
  inline float f() const {return b;};
  void ff(int x);
};

class B{
      
  A *pointer = nullptr;

public:
  B();
  bool g(A object, const string &p);
  bool gg(int x);
};







void A::ff(int x){
  b += x;
};


bool B::g(A object, const string &pin){   // SOLVED, here should be A &object
  pointer = &object;
  return true;
}

bool B::gg(int x){
  pointer->ff(x);
  return true;
}
```

The main program

```
A object("9876", 100);  
B obj(10);
obj.g(object, "9876");
obj.gg(20);
object.f();       //This should return 120, but it returns 100
```

Comment: You should change `acceptCard` to accept a reference to `DebitCard `. Otherwise, `pCard = &acard;` is storing the address of the parameter, which is copy. Do a search for "C++ pass by reference vs. pass by value".

Comment: Oh, I get it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Rules for use of raw pointers in C++: 1: don't do it. 2: (for experts only) don't do it now.

Comment: The code should fail to compile because the constructor definition for `DebitCard::DebitCard` has 5 parameters while it was declared with only 3

Comment: @Jerry Coffin  could you explain more what you mean. I'm just starting with C++ and coding at all, so it would be very helpful.

Comment: @M.M yeah, I'm sorry. I tried to delete all unnecesery parts of code. This one I forget.

Comment: @abc it's good to check your code reproduces the problem and then copy paste that code. Instead of trying to edit it in the question box,  chances are you introduce errors that may obscure the real problem

Comment: @M.M Yeah, you're right. I will remember that.

Comment: @JerryCoffin that is not applicable if the entire point is to learn about pointers.

Comment: Mostly I mean that when you use pointers, it's really easy to get things wrong, and rarely a whole lot of reason to deal with them directly, so most of the time, you're better off just avoiding them. And C++ has enough alternatives that most of the time, you can do what you need to without using them.

Comment: @user253751: At least in my opinion, the entire point should never be to learn about pointers (or any other specific feature). Generally, you should be starting from what you want to accomplish, and learning the features that allow you to accomplish that well, not starting from a feature and trying to find ways to use it (or something on that order).

Comment: @JerryCoffin If you don't know pointers then you don't know C++ - full stop.

Comment: @user253751: I'll admit, I've a bit of uncertainty about exactly what "know C++" means. Thanks for helping clarify.

Comment: @JerryCoffin so better alternative would be to use smart pointers? In this case unique ptr? Or?

Comment: In this case, it looks like you can probably do everything necessary with a reference instead (and when you can, that's generally preferable).

Comment: @JerryCoffin I have to disagree. Knowing and using pointers is critical for C++.  I think that avoiding _owning_ raw pointers is the right idea, but not avoiding raw pointers full-stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In c++, class instances are not passed by reference by default. Therefore,

```cpp
bool ATM::acceptCard(DebitCard acard, const string &pin)
```

this function takes a copy of DebitCard and stores the address of this copy. Next call to `ATM::deposit` will use a pointer that doesn't point to a valid object.

To make this code work, `ATM::acceptCard` function should either take a pointer and store this pointer directly, or take a reference and store the address of referenced object.

Answer (score 1):

pointers are just that. Points to a value on memory. The difference between pointers and references is pointers point to the value and the reference points to de address where the value is stored.

```
int a = 2;
int b = 3;
int i = *a;
int *p = &b;
cout << i << ", " << *p << ", " << &b <<endl;
```

output is: 2, 3, 'memory address where b is stored'

Answer (score 0):

```
bool ATM::acceptCard(DebitCard acard, const string &pin){
  pCard = &acard;
  return true;
}
```

You're storing the address of the `acard` object that was created to hold the value passed to this function and will be destroyed when the function completes. You cannot later access the object that pointer points to because as soon as this function ends, it no longer points to an object.

It's no different from this:

```
int* somePointer;

// ...

void foo(int j)
{
    somePointer = &j;
}

// ...

foo(3);
*somePointer = 4; // what object's value is being changed here?!
```

The `3` that `foo` received doesn't exist after `foo` returns. So `somePointer` points to nothing. And the `*somePointer = 4;` makes no sense. What object would hold the value 4?